# Garageband - Remove Dead Space at End of Track

Tags: garageband

I was sidetracked while recording something off of the internet into Garageband. How do I cut off all of the dead space at the end of my recording?

Comment: Did you try selecting the recorded content, copying it, and then pasting into a new track?

Comment: You can't just click at the end of the track and drag backwards until you get to actual recording? Are you asking about deleting that space in GarageBand or iTunes?

Answer (score 2):

By saying *cut off all of the dead space*, I assume you wanna crop the track to remove silence at the end of the track? If I'm right, here is 1 solution:

1. Add the track to your iTunes
2. Right click on track and Get Info (or just <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>)
3. Select Options tab
4. Tick stop, and select time you want track to end and press ok
5. Go to iTunes Preferences: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma)
6. In General tab, click on Import Settings and select your output format, eg. MP3, then ok
7. Click on your song, go File > Convert > Create MP3/AAC version
8. When this is complete you can find this track by right clicking on it and say Show in Finder

Hope this is what you wanted? If not, it might help someone else as this option has been silently removed from the right-click context menu. :) Let us know.